# instance of CKeditor already exists

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I have found a few similar posts on this on Stack overflow but there are none with an answer that is working.

I have a few tabs on a page, depending on that li they click on they will see a specific tab. In one of the tabs there is a CKeditor which is initiated on the click of the li. When they user clicks off that specific tab onto another one, and then returns there is this error:

> Uncaught The editor instance "employDesc" is already attached to the
>   provided element.

Here is the JS:

```
    $('.addVacancy').click( function() {
        if(CKEDITOR.instances.employDesc)  {
            alert('instance exists');
            var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[employDesc];
            if (editor) { 
                editor.destroy(true); 
            } 
            alert('distroyed');
        }   
        CKEDITOR.replace('employDesc');
    });
```

Both of the alerts appear but then it breaks as the error comes on in the console. Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: why do you wanna bind CKEDITOR on click event of the li? why not bind it on document load ?

Comment: I tried that, but when I clicked through the tabs it didnt work. I thought maybe they were dynamically loaded

Comment: Can you do a working fiddle of this ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're trying to use a variable named `employDesc`, you should use `CKEDITOR.instances["employDesc"]`;
or just

```
$('.addVacancy').click( function() {
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.employDesc;
    if (editor) {
        alert('instance exists');
        editor.destroy(true); 
        alert('destroyed');
    }   
    CKEDITOR.replace('employDesc');
});
```

It's the same that you were trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (CKEDITOR.instances['tresc']) {
    CKEDITOR.remove(CKEDITOR.instances['tresc']);
} else{
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'tresc');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using something like this code to check if the editor is not defined before, create a new instance. I think this is better from those I have tried.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.['employDesc'];
    if (!editor){
        CKEDITOR.replace('employDesc');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i couldn't find any solutions posted online that worked. but this worked for me:

```
var notes = 'div-name';
$('#'+notes).html('');
CKEDITOR.appendTo( notes );
```

instead of CKEDITOR.replace, I used CKEDITOR.appendTo

hope this saves some poor soul some precious time.